# Heading taking more than container size, when restricting screen size to mobile width

Tags: html, css

I have a heading inside a div container which is in turn inside another container

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}

.login_box {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 70px;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0.98;
}

.login_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.login_header h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="login_box">
    <div class="login_header">
      <h1>FanZentral.com</h1>
      Login or sign up below!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now when I reduce the width of the screen to mobile size. the heading is taking up more space than the container it is in, can somebody help in making sure the `login box` remains at fixed length even after moving down to mobile size?

Comment: Have you tried max-width: 100%; ?

Comment: i have added the styling max-width:100% in login box. but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a min-width property to your .login_box. See below:

```
.login_box {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 70px;
    width: 35%;
    min-width:min-content;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    opacity: 0.98;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look if it helps.I set the width to min-content and added padding to it.**

```css
.login_header {
  width: min-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.heady {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  padding: 22px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 250%;
}

.below {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="login_box">

  <div class="login_header">
    <div class="heady">FanZentral.com</div>
    <div class='below'>Login or sign up below!</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.